# Jquery : Take the exact value from the xml

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml

I the below xml,arrival-date-time is coming 2 times in xml but i need the first arrival-date-time,

```
<segment>
      <index>1</index>
      <departure-airport>MAA</departure-airport>
      <arrival-airport>IXB</arrival-airport>
      <departure-date-time>2015-03-17T07:55:00</departure-date-time>
      <arrival-date-time>2015-03-17T11:45:00</arrival-date-time>
      <flight-number>503</flight-number>
      <airline>6E</airline>
      <operating-airline>6E</operating-airline>
      <stops>1</stops>
      <equipment>320 </equipment>
      <duration>13800</duration>
      <stops-details>
          <stop-details>
              <layover-airport>CCU</layover-airport>
              <arrival-date-time>2015-03-17T10:10:00</arrival-date-time>
              <departure-date-time>2015-03-17T10:40:00</departure-date-time>
              <layover-duration>1800</layover-duration>
          </stop-details>
      </stops-details>
    </segment>
```

---

I tried like this, but not working. Any help is appreciated !!!!

```
var arr_tym =$(element).find('departure-date-time').text();
```

This was working for me, but in IE8 its not working

```
var arr_tym =$(element).find('arrival-date-time')[0].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `:first` to select just the first

```js
var xml = '<segment> \
      <index>1</index> \
      <departure-airport>MAA</departure-airport> \
      <arrival-airport>IXB</arrival-airport> \
      <departure-date-time>2015-03-17T07:55:00</departure-date-time> \
      <arrival-date-time>2015-03-17T11:45:00</arrival-date-time> \
      <flight-number>503</flight-number> \
      <airline>6E</airline> \
      <operating-airline>6E</operating-airline> \
      <stops>1</stops> \
      <equipment>320 </equipment> \
      <duration>13800</duration> \
      <stops-details> \
          <stop-details> \
              <layover-airport>CCU</layover-airport> \
              <arrival-date-time>2015-03-17T10:10:00</arrival-date-time> \
              <departure-date-time>2015-03-17T10:40:00</departure-date-time> \
              <layover-duration>1800</layover-duration> \
          </stop-details> \
      </stops-details> \
    </segment>';

var arr_tym =$(xml).find('departure-date-time:first').text();
console.log(arr_tym);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```